# Replace only words inside a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am using a regex replace to `<mark></mark>` input text. The problem I am running into is that it takes all text from a holder div and replaces it into a variable and adds the mark tags. Then places it back into the div holder. When I do this, if I type in `"<p>"`, it highlights the actual `<p>` and outputs it back into the div.

Is there anyway to get around this? Here is my marking code:

```
function Search() {
    var Notes = document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML;
    var i = document.getElementById("Bar").value;
    var inputReOne = $.trim(i);
    var inp = inputReOne.replace(".", "\.").replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace(
        "/", "").replace(/\\/, "");
    document.getElementById("Bar").value = inp;
    if ($.trim(inp) !== '') {
        var InpComp = inp.toUpperCase();
        var Ind = tags.indexOf(InpComp);
        if (Ind === -1) {
            var inpReg = new RegExp(inp, "im");
            var WordCheck = Notes.match(inpReg);
            if (WordCheck !== null) {
                tags.push(InpComp);
                var SearchReq = new RegExp("(" + inp + ")", "gim");
                var after = Notes.replace(SearchReq, "<mark class=" +
                    ColorOptionReady + ">$1</mark>");
                document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML = after;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div> 
       <p id="form"> 
           <input class="SearchInp" autocomplete="off" id="Bar" name="Input" type="text" placeholder="Search for word or phrase"> 
           <input class="SearchInp" type="submit" id="sea" onClick="Search ()" value="Search"> <div id="NoteHolder">
       </p>
       <p class="NoteOp" id="NoteOne">This is a test paragraph uses to TeSt filters.</p> 
       <p class="NoteOp" id="NoteTwo">Random words, I need to see if it will mess up mark</p> 
   </div>
<script src="Test.js"></script>
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That first line in your function could use `.textContent` instead. PS: I don't know if you've seen [the famous Zalgo answer about HTML+Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2773837).

Comment: @Hatchet How would I keep the same placement though? If I have two paragraphs and I use this (It works), how would I add the `<p>` tags back?

Comment: Could you post your HTML (maybe add as a snippet)? That would help some.

Comment: @Hawkeye you can edit your original question. I think that would be clearer than leaving the code in a comment :)

Comment: That HTML seems malformed.

Comment: @franklin Some of the code wasn't indented far enough! Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than searching and replacing in the `#NoteHolder` element, why not loop through each `.NoteOp` and replace in there?

```js
function search() {
  var notes = document.getElementsByClassName("NoteOp");
  var s = document.getElementById("Bar").value.trim();
  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    var n = notes[i];
    n.innerHTML = n.textContent.replace(new RegExp("(" + s + ")", "gim"), "<mark>$1</mark>");
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="SearchInp" autocomplete="off" id="Bar" name="Input" type="text" placeholder="Search for word or phrase">
<input class="SearchInp" type="submit" id="sea" onClick="search()" value="Search">
<div id="NoteHolder">
  <p class="NoteOp" id="NoteOne">This is a test paragraph uses to TeSt filters.</p>
  <p class="NoteOp" id="NoteTwo">Random words, I need to see if it will mess up mark</p>
</div>
```

Note: Storing the contents of each `.NoteOp` in an object, working with the text in there and simply setting the content of each `.NoteOp` after every search would be easier and cleaner.

Comment: Works great but would there be a way to maintain previous inputs? So if I search up "uses" then I search "test" keep "uses" marked and add "test" to the marks.

Comment: The problem now is that if I have a search (Let's say `test`), then I search `mark` it highlights the actual mark tag but I still want it to save pervious searches. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Hawkeye Keep an array of searches.

Comment: I do have one already but how would I loop it to search for all again?

Comment: @Hawkeye Right now the regex is `new RegExp("(" + s + ")", "gim")`. After adding `s` to the array of searches, change that line to `new RegExp("(" + searches.join("|") + ")", "gim")`.

Comment: Now I am at the problem that I am using another function that adds the color class. I want it to maintain the color.

Comment: @Hawkeye If you have a different problem, please ask another question.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I decided just to add the `\b` selector onto the regex to avoid the actual html marking.